# User Login time restriction

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2000

I have shifts in my application. I want to restrict the time that a user can log in to their defined log in time span.

Shift 1 which is AM to PM is working fine, but PM to AM check is creating problems. This is because the second shift starts at 5.00 PM and ends on next day on 10.00am.

The user table structure is

```
shiftid,  starttime,  endtime
1,        6:00:00 AM, 11:30:00 PM
2,        5:00:00 PM, 10:00:00 AM
```

Comment: what kind of problem does it create? and where do you grab your timeshifts? directly in SQL?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are currently using, and cite where you are having problems?

Comment: I need this in desktop application, and code is here
tNow = Format(Now, "hh:mm tt")'' current time
 stTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("starttime"), "hh:mm tt") 'get time start from table
 edTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("endtime"), "hh:mm tt") ''get time end from table
                If tNow > stTime And tNow < edTime Then
                    bShift = True '' mean it is time to start shift
                End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that starttime and endtime are time values in your table, you can use the following:

```
DECLARE
  @timenow TIME

-- Get the current time  
SELECT @timenow = CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE())

SELECT * 
  FROM temp
         -- This clause handles the case where the shifts don't go past midnight
 WHERE ((endtime > starttime) AND (@timenow BETWEEN starttime AND endtime))

         -- This clause handles the case where the shifts do go past midnight
    OR ((endtime < starttime) AND (@timenow >= starttime OR @timenow <= endtime))
```

If your values are not stored with a data type of `Time`, you can convert them like:

```
CONVERT(TIME, starttime)
```

**Update**

To do this in your code, you need to change the following line:

```
If tNow > stTime And tNow < edTime Then
```

to match the logic in the sql:

```
If tNow >= stTime OrElse tNow <= edTime Then
```

This makes the code:

```
    Dim tNow As String
    Dim stTime As String
    Dim edTime As String

    tNow = Format(Date.Now, "hh:mm tt")

    stTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("starttime"), "hh:mm tt")
    edTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("endtime"), "hh:mm tt")
    If stTime < edTime Then
        If tNow >= stTime OrElse tNow <= edTime Then
            bShift = True
        End If
    Else
        If tNow >= stTime And tNow <= edTime Then
            bShift = True
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I have convert this code in vb.net but it did not work. when the mid night will over timenow will less then starttime. let us say start time is 5.00PM and in case of mid night over time will 1.am. now 1.00am is less 5.00pm so it wil not work.

Comment: @nbhatti2001: I suspect the issue is in you vb conversion then, because I did test and verify that this would work. The logic for the past midnight shift is contained in the second where clause: if the end time (1 am) is less than the start time (5pm) then the shift goes past midnight. So then we check if the current time (11pm) >= starttime (5pm) (true) or current time (11pm) <= endtime (1am) (false), then the shift is selected. Note that this logic depends on comparing time only on a 24 hour clock, which will be more complicated to do in vb.

Comment: If you edit your question to include the code that you are having problems with, I can take a look and see where you are having issues. Should be pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: My logic is here
                tNow = Format(Now, "hh:mm tt")
                stTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("starttime"), "hh:mm tt")
                edTime = Format(ds.Tables("shiftdetails").Rows(0).Item("endtime"), "hh:mm tt")
                If stTime < edTime Then
                    If tNow > stTime And tNow < edTime Then
                        bShift = True
                    End If
                Else
                    If tNow >= stTime And tNow <= edTime Then
                        bShift = True
                    End If
                End If

Answer (score 0):

```
select .... where timeWork >= TimeStart and timeWork < TimeEnd  
               and timeStart < timeEnd 
            or    timeWork <= TimeStart and timeWork > TimeEnd 
               and timeStart < timeEnd
```